# declaring a const inside a try/catch block with await

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I currently have this:

```
var item_id
try {
    item_id =
        await
            (async function () {
               // code
            })();
} catch (error) {

}
```

But I'd much prefer having `item_id` as a const. What's the best way to assign the await value to a const, given that node requires me to handle promise rejection

e.g. Errors:

```
[0] (node:77118) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: details[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
[0] (node:77118) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**Async code**

```
await
    (async function () {
        const query = `
            INSERT INTO item (list_id)
            SELECT 
                ?
            FROM
                list
            WHERE
                id = ?
                AND
                user_id = ?
            LIMIT 1;
        `

        const results =
            await
                doQuery({
                    inputs: [
                        list_id,
                        list_id,
                        req.session.user.id
                        // 10
                    ],
                    query,
                    error_message: "item create mysql error"
                })
        return results.insertId === 0 ? false : results.insertId
    })();
```

doQuery

```
function doQuery({ query, inputs, error_message, res = null }) {
    return (
        new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            db.query(query, inputs, function (err, results, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    console.trace(chalk.green(db.sql))
                    console.log()
                    handleError({ error: err, error_message, res })
                    reject(err)
                    return
                }

                resolve(results)
            })
        })
    )
}
```

handleError

```
function handleError({ error, message, res }) {
    console.trace(chalk.yellow(message))
    console.trace(chalk.red(error))
    console.log()

    if (res) {
        res.send({
            error: true,
            success: false,
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you handling the error, or ignoring it, leaving `item_id` as `undefined`?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I actually have an error handler inside the async function which is imported from another file

Comment: Can you post a little more of your code? So we get the full grasp of what you have, and how it can be improved.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande updated, hopefully enough

Answer (score 7):

This is a well-known problem which has been discussed elsewhere.

Your options include:

1. Just declaring `item_id` with `let` at the outer level as you have done. Nothing wrong with that.
2. Depending on what you want to do with `item_id`, do that inside the `try/catch` block, allowing you to declare `const item_id;` inside the `try`.
3. Make sure you really need a `try/catch`. Remember that any error thrown inside an `async` function will automatically translate into a rejection of the promise being returned by the function. You don't have to (and in may cases don't want to) catch it; instead, handle the error at a higher level. Node "requiring you to handle promise rejection" does not mean you have to handle it right here where it occurs; you can handle it at any higher level. Remember that `catch`'ing the error here will put the async function back on the "happy path" (unless you re-throw) and the calling function will have no way of knowing there was an error.
4. In some cases, your code will be more readable if you go back to using promises, and `.catch()`, as in

   ```
   const item_id_promise = async function () {}();

   item_id_promise.catch(...);
   ```

   or possibly even just

   ```
   return (async function() { }()).catch(...)
   ```

But actually your question has nothing to do with `await`, `async`, or promises. It's just about block-scoping of variables inside blocks, in this case a `try` block. Yes, `const` and `let` are block-scoped, and therefor are scoped to the `try` clause. So like anything else, if you want to use them outside the `try` block, you have to declare them outside the `try` block. Or, if you really don't want to declare them outside the `try` block, you can't use them outside the `try` block, so you have to arrange to use them only inside it, if that's possible.

Comment: yeah, I've just chosen to wrap the entire thing in a `try... catch`

Answer (score 1):

Following @torazaburo's suggestion:

```
const item_id = async function () {
  // code
  return 1337; // return your expected item id
}();
item_id.catch(function (e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: This looks like you're assigning a `function` to item_id. This lambda function isn't actually being invoked. Am I reading this incorrectly?

Comment: I still need the item_id to be retrieve synchronously because I need it for inserting other rows later on.

Comment: How does this solve anything?  `item_id` here is a function, not a value.

Answer (score 1):

You could define your function in another scope using the power of Promises such as:

```
async function foo(bar) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         if(bar === 'baz') {
              resolve(bar); // Resolve this promise
         } else {
              reject(); // Reject this promise
         }
    });
}

foo('baz').then(baz => {
    // Do something with 'baz', the result of the resolved promise
}).catch(error => {
    // The promise is rejected, process an error here
});
```

Comment: But it's a safe assumption that entire thrust of the OP's question related to using `async/await` and catching errors by means of `try/catch` blocks around that.